# how multi images appear in the Picture box with the file name in the datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, picturebox, vb.net-2010

I want to appear multi or a single image in the picturebox with the file name in the datagridview when clicked on datagridview.

for information I use visual studio 2010

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
  Dim Path As String = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DBF"
    Dim Pathimage As String = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CATALOG"
    Dim cn = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV"
    Private Sub PopulateDataGridView()
        Try
            Dim dt = New DataTable()
            Dim query = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS,FILENAME1,FILENAME2,FILENAME3,FILENAME4 FROM ITEM"

            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn.ToString)
                adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using

            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PopulateDataGridView()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: RESULT DATAGRIDVIEW WITH FILENAME]

Comment: Where should the images appear?

Comment: What have you tried? You filled the grid but I don't see any code that attempts to show a picture.

Comment: You are going to have to provide more info about what you are trying to achieve and what is not working as expected. I see nothing in the code in relation to a `PictureBox` or adding images to a grid’s cell. Please [edit] your question to provide a better context and what is not working. Your title… _”how multi image appears when clicked on datagridview in the picturebox”_ … is vague and it is difficult to ascertain what you are asking.

Comment: And if you could explain the connection/data relationship between the spreadsheet and query results your showing in your screenshots

Comment: @djv , I want the picture to appear in the picturebox. so based on the ITC column and if based on the filename I provided then before the sign "(","-","." and space. Is it possible to display multi images in picture box?

Comment: @Mary ,so based on the ITC column and if based on the filename I provided then before the sign "(","-","." and space. Is it possible to display multi images in picture box?. So I'm asking you for a solution

Comment: @djv , so based on datagridview the ITC column then connects to the catalog folder (List filename image) but previously took the filename data in its catalog folder before the sign "(","-",".", and spaced

Comment: @Mary , so based on datagridview the ITC column then connects to the catalog folder (List filename image) but previously took the filename data in its catalog folder before the sign "(","-",".", and spaced

Comment: @JohnG , I want a code solution to display images in the picturebox of datagridview. Sorry if my explanation wasn't what you expected. so based on datagridview the ITC column then connects to the catalog folder (List filename image) but previously took the filename data in its catalog folder before the sign "(","-",".", and spaced. Is it possible to display multi images in picture box?

Comment: @Hursey ,the screenshot I displayed in excel was the contents of the catalog folder. so based on datagridview the ITC column then connects to the catalog folder (List filename image) but previously took the filename data in its catalog folder before the sign "(","-",".", and spaced. Is it possible to display multi images in picture box?

Comment: _”Is it possible to display multi images in picture box?”_ … NO … I could be mistaken, however; I am confident you cannot add multiple `Image` files to a single `PictureBox`. … additionally… _”I want a code solution to display images in the picturebox of datagridview.”_ ?... A `DataGridView` does NOT have a `PictureBox` so it is unclear what you mean. The `DataGridView` DOES have a `DataGridViewImageColumn` and a `DataGridViewImageCell` to display images in cells in the grid. It appears you may be asking multiple questions and it is unclear how the posted code relates to your question(s).

Comment: Lastly… I mean no disrespect; however, I am not sure if I follow your comment… _”Sorry if my explanation wasn't what you expected.”_ … ? … It is fairly irrelevant what “MY“ expectations are… however … StackOverflow may have some expectations of YOU when asking questions. In addition for your own benefit… if YOU don’t articulate the problem in a clear and concise fashion that others can understand and reproduce… and you end up with a bunch of unnecessary back and forth questions… then … who’s fault is that? In this case it seems like you are asking multiple questions with no clear focus.

Comment: So when you say "catalog folder",  Is that a Directory your computer has access too?  As for showing multiple images, you're getting into a Master-Detail/Parent-Child data relationship.  For this you will need to work out exactly how you want users to interact with your app.  For Example, Double click the ITC number, which will pop up a second form.  Second form loads files into a DataTable then have another DGV with an DataGridViewImageColumn to display it.  There is a lot more logic for you to map out on that

Comment: @JohnG , Your comments are too long and do not provide a solution. Actually there is a solution with a path or filename in the datagridview column then later it will refer to the picturebox or there is another solution. If you don't like my post or can't solve the problem or don't provide a solution then you don't need to comment too long

Comment: @Hursey , for the "catalog folder" it is my computer's locale . Master data relationship means there are other files. if without a master data relationship with the filename in the datagridview column is it possible to appear? and Like the example you mean click 2 in the ITC column but appears in picturebox1,picturebox2,picturebox3,picturebox4 is it possible?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you're understanding.  You have your Master is the ITC record, the detail is each file.  How you display that is 100% up to you and your requirements.  I'm suggesting one way is to load a 2nd DVG with the images.  Weather that is on a 2nd form or not is completely up to you

Comment: @Hursey , Thank you for your reply. Can you give an example of a code according to your advice?

Comment: Any question that requires this much discussion to clarify is not up to Stack Overflow standards. Vote to close. BTW, comments are not meant to provided solutions.

Comment: @Mary , thanks for your reply. Can you give me an answer to my post?

Comment: No one can answer your question really,  there is a whole heap of design decisions you need to make.  You’ve had some suggestions, you need to decide what is the appropriate solution to satisfy your requirements

Comment: @Hursey , I added screenshot of datagridview with filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a FlowLayoutPanel to your form, and paste this handler for DataGridView1 SelectionChanged

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    Dim row = DirectCast(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
    Dim pbAdder =
        Sub(name As String)
            If row(name) IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row(name).ToString()) Then
                FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(New PictureBox With {.Name = name, .ImageLocation = row(name).ToString()})
            End If
        End Sub
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()
    pbAdder("FILENAME1")
    pbAdder("FILENAME2")
    pbAdder("FILENAME3")
    pbAdder("FILENAME4")
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. in your code there is a "?" so I removed from that code and from your code where is image path without filename "Dim Pathimage As String = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CATALOG"". so the image doesn't appear in the FlowLayoutPanel

Comment: can it show pictures from folders & subfolders?

Comment: @roy The `?` is there as a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) and is critical to the code working but now I see you are using Visual Studio 2010 and it probably isn't valid syntax for you so I'll rewrite it without it.

Comment: @roy according to your question, this is answered. You showed the filenames as is, and how can anyone know that you are missing the directory? You can combine the directory and filename with `Path.Combine(directory, filename)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This is my directory : "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CATALOG" Like the answer from you using `Path.Combine(directory, filename)`. So I'm still confused using the code `Path.Combine(directory, filename)` in flowlayoutpanel then first please you can update in your answer code? and second how the image that appears in flowlayoutpanel can autosize and update also in your answer?

Comment: @roy I'm going to stop answering your questions. You want code written for you but there is a degree of expectation that you can take a piece of code and modify it to make it work, and you have not shown that.

Comment: sorry I'm late in replying, even though you didn't answer the question so I will mark your answer that I have received as a solution. thank you very much

Comment: @roy I did answer the Question. You just keep adding more questions through comments. Try to make your Questions more complete

Comment: Well, I'll make a new question.